# Revert to an older version of a file

Tags: git, xcode4.3

I am quite sure there are plenty of resources on how to get back to an older version of a file, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2733873/reverting-a-single-file-to-a-previous-version-in-git), but using the command line, what i want to do is the same but from the Xcode interfaces. Is there any way to do so? thanx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The only way that I know of is to locate the prior version of the file, copy the contents to the working version, and commit the result.  You find all earlier versions using the 'Version Editor' pane, clicking the 'Timeline' icon and then scrolling through the versions (say on the right).  Once there select the version you want and copy the content.