# How to undo a git commit and rollback to previous version for selected file only?

Tags: git, bitbucket

I have committed few files in local. Now I want to rollback 1 file to previous version.

Example:
committed: A, B, C

Want to:
commit: A, C
Rollback: B

Can anyone help me?

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reverting a single file to a previous version in git](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2733873/reverting-a-single-file-to-a-previous-version-in-git)

Answer (score 1):

You want to use `git checkout` or `git show`:

```
git checkout B -- path/to/file
```

Or:

```
git show B:./path/to/file > ./path/to/file
```

Then add and commit as usual.

Comment: this is for a specific file - how can we do it for an entire merge pull ?

Comment: @RickyLevi You want to use `git revert`.  The trick here is that you'll need to know which parent to select.  Look at the documentation on the `-m` flag in the [git revert man page](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-revert) for more details.