# Git revert certain files

Tags: git, git-revert

I want to do a revert of a commit, but only for some files. (*Not a checkout; a revert.* If you are unfamiliar with the difference, keep reading.)

I tried this

```
git revert --no-commit abcdef123456 -- my/path/to/revert
```

And I got this error

```
fatal: ambiguous argument 'my/path/to/revert': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions
```

But that is precisely what I did! (And yes, `my/path/to/revert` is in my working tree.)

My working theory is that it is not possible to revert only some files, and that the Git error message is misleading.

(Git 1.7.9.5)

---

**This is not a duplicate** of [Reverting a single file to a previous version in git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2733873/reverting-a-single-file-to-a-previous-version-in-git).

- That question (despite the title) pertains to *git-checkout*. A checkout restores a file to a previous version, removing all commits after that point.
- My question pertains to *git-revert*. A revert undoes changes made in a particular commit, without touching other commits that may have come later. It applies the reverse of (only) that commit.

Comment: Can you explain your need to `revert` instead of using `checkout`? As far as I know, a checkout of the appropriate files followed by a commit would be equivalent to a revert.

Comment: I don't think you can revert a single file, where did you read that, is it in the docs? You can however apply patches in reverse, together with git apply: `git show <commit> -- <path> | git apply -R`, found here: http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/Revert-a-single-commit-in-a-single-file-td6064050.html

Comment: I think this might be a duplicate of this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2733873/reverting-a-single-file-to-a-previous-version-in-git

Comment: @ChrisMaes, see my explanation of the difference between `checkout` and `revert`.

Comment: @PaulDraper, interesting, apparently I've misunderstood `revert` for years. So if you have commits `A` (older), `B`, and `C`, you want to reverse the changes from `A` while keeping the changes from the newer commits `B` and `C`.

Comment: @steabert, that is a reasonable option in my case.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A shorter sequence for when you can make a short list of what you want:

```
git revert that_commit           # do the whole revert
git reset --hard HEAD^           # in what turns out to have been a throwaway commit
git checkout HEAD@{1} -- one/folder   # and just take what you want of the results
```

Answer (score 33):

I don't think git lets you specify particular files to revert. The best I can think of is this:

```sh
git revert --no-commit <commit hash> # Revert, don't commit it yet
git reset # Unstage everything
git add yourFilesToRevert # Add the file to revert
git commit -m "commit message"
git reset --hard # Undo changes from the part of the revert that we didn't commit
```

Comment: FWIW, it should be pretty easy to wrap this up in a shell script make it easier if you find yourself doing this a lot.

Comment: Alternatively, if you want to keep most files in the revert and only undo a few, you can do the git-revert, use `git reset --hard` on the files you don't want reverted, then commit.

Answer (score 9):

[vcsjones' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23068984/1256452) is probably the best way since revert uses the three-way merge machinery.  However, for many cases, you could `git apply -R` (reverse) the patch to the file (or files) in question, e.g.:

```
git show <rev> -- path/to/file | git apply -R
```

(or `git diff`—any diff generator that allow you to limit the result to specific files, really—but `git show` is the obvious go-to for non-merge commits; for merges you'd need to specify the correct parent).

Comment: This certainly is the simplest way.

Comment: This is less robust than the other answers: `error: patch failed: ...\n error: ...: patch does not apply`

Comment: @jimbo1qaz: yes, that's why I said vcsjones' answer is probably best in general (though jthill's is just as good, and probably easier—it didn't exist at the time I wrote the above).

Answer (score 0):

Git works by commits. You cannot git revert a file. Even if there's just one file in a commit, you are still reverting the commit. The solution is to emulate git revert to get back what you need for a new commit. I don't see the cleanest and safest way shown here - revert on another branch and checkout what you need. Unlike git apply, it won't break if there are merge conflicts and revert/reset really only lends itself to undoing one commit.

```
git checkout -b tmpbranch
git revert commitref                   # complete commit, follow with more reverts as needed
git checkout mainbranch
git checkout tmpbranch -- file/i/need  # while on mainbranch and to index by default
git commit -m "this is a new commit message"
git branch -d tmpbranch
```