# How can i undo changes between two commits?

Tags: git

I want revert one file changes between two commit,

```
commit 1 hash: abcde1....
   some code changes

commit 2 hash : abcde2....
   some code changes

commit 3 hash : abcde3....
   some code changes

.....
```

i can use `git checkout abcde3 -- file/to/restore` and revert to commit 3, but lost commit 1 changes,
How can i checkout only commit 2 changes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply use [`git revert`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-revert).

Revert commit 2, and that will create a new commit which cancels any changes introduced by said commit 2.

If `git revert` (which operates at the commit level, and `not` for a single file) reverts too many file, you can [reset the files you did not want reverted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23068984/6309).

```
git revert --no-commit <commit hash> # Revert, don't commit it yet
git reset # Unstage everything
git add yourFilesToRevert # Add the file to revert
git commit -m "commit message"
git reset --hard # Undo changes from the part of the revert that we didn't commit
```

Comment: @rujgii Exactly: that is what the second part of my answer addresses: the ability to revert a specific commit (commit2) just for *one* file.