# how do I access content of a submodule in github?

Tags: github

I don't know how, but I somehow turned a file into a submodule. So now I can't view it in Github. How do I undo this, to make the file clickable again?

(I've read through answers to similar question in stackoverflow, and they don't make much sense to me...I'm pretty new to git)

Answer (score 0):

You either need to [revert to a past commit where that file was not a submodule](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2733873/6309):

```
git log path/to/file
git checkout <past_commit> -- path/to/file
```

Or you could delete that entry and restore the file, adding it and committing it again.

```
git rm -- path/to/file
# copy the file
git add -- path/to/file
git commit -m "restore file"
```