# Doxygen and git for automated file version information

Tags: git, doxygen

is there a way to get information for Doxygen from git:
For instance for:

```
@version
@author
@date
```

The information should be automatically included in the Doxygen comments.

For `@version` it would be nice to get maybe the tag information.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [git revision number in source code documentation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7016300/git-revision-number-in-source-code-documentation)

Comment: Read [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/62264/dealing-with-svn-keyword-expansion-with-git-svn#72874)

Answer (score 7):

I realize this is an older question, but I was just trying to do the same thing.

Neither of the linked answers in the comments are a great solution to this issue.  We may want to include e.g. a git revision in the *generated* documentation without mucking about with git filters and so forth in our working sources.

Fortunately, Doxygen supports the use of environment variables in your `Doxyfile`, and provides various settings that can be used to place information in your generated content.  The `PROJECT_NUMBER` setting is meant explicitly for including version control information in your documentation.

If we have this in our `Doxyfile`:

```
PROJECT_NUMBER = $(PROJECT_NUMBER)
```

You can run `doxygen` like this to include the git revision in your generated docs:

```
PROJECT_NUMBER=$(git rev-parse --short HEAD) doxygen
```

You're not limited to just the commit id, either.  For example:

```
PROJECT_NUMBER=$(git log -1 --format "%h (%cd)") doxygen
```

This makes the title in my generated HTML look like:

```
<div id="projectname">MyProject
&#160;<span id="projectnumber">9dd847b (Fri Feb 1 15:36:13 2019 -0500)</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Note that this technique also works on Windows, though you will (probably) want to have a wrapper script and use one of the techniques described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2768608/batch-equivalent-of-bash-backticks)

Comment: One can also just append the new definition of `PROJECT_NUMBER` to the configuration. For example I have this as a pre-build step in Jenkins: `echo "PROJECT_NUMBER = \"version in git: \""$(git describe --always --dirty --long) >> doxyfile-jenkins.cfg`. Where `doxyfile-jenkins.cfg` is a local copy of the configuration not part of the git index.