# How to change the SHA-1 of a specific commit in place with git?

Tags: git

The target commit may have parents and descendants.

it needs to replace the old commit **in place**,

so it's not as simple as `cherry` command.

My question will wait for an **exact** solution.

Comment: The hash of a given commit depends upon a bunch of things including the content, author, date, and the hash of its parent. If you change a commit's hash (by `--amend` or rebasing) this will also change the hashes of all of its "children". You can fake this with grafts, but I think the *precise* thing you're asking for isn't possible.

Comment: Maybe you could tell us the problem you're trying to solve (rather than the solution that you want)?

Answer (score 4):

No, you can't do that.

The point of SHA-1 is to prevent changes like these. The whole git architecture depends on the assumption that SHA-1 uniquely identify the object in all git repository. No way to workaround this (not without redesigning everything, that is).

The details are explained in the [Git Magic book](http://www-cs-students.stanford.edu/~blynn/gitmagic/ch08.html).

Comment: It's very improbable,but it still has the CHANCE. That's what my question bases upon.

Comment: It is to "... prevent accidental or malicious data corruption.". Computer see changes as changes, what you are doing is just the same as "malicious data corruption". There were some discussion on that on the git list, search for SHA-512 on it.

Comment: Please refer to the comments under this answer if you have problem understanding it MAY happen(though the chance is slim): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7062192/about-gits-merge-and-rebase/7062773#7062773

Comment: Just as a matter of fact. Git does not store *changes* (as `diff`, like cvs do), it store the *state* (the `treeish` thingy). If you want to (let's say) delete a file, you need to change all the commit containing the file.

Comment: I DO know that git stores snapshot instead of delta,thanks to the   previous answer:)

Comment: @asker: I agree with J-1's answer, and don't think you will find another solution. A `rebase --interactive` to remove the commit you don't want, plus a `git fetch` remains your best bet... but it is hardly an 'in place' solution.

Comment: Right,to make it `in place` needs to change the parent and son of a specific node.

Comment: Or, if you so hated that commit. You can remove the commit object file, then `git-log` will never show up that commit again.  The drawback would be.... you don't be able to do `push`/`pull` (like a shadow `git clone --depth` repository)

Comment: I don't hate it,just want to change it's SHA-1.I know it's not available out of the box, the work-around is to `cherry` another commit with the same content,and then **replace that old commit**.But how to do the step in bold?

Comment: @asker, ok, lets see my new answer is better. For me, it is too ugly to be considered "works".

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Git but in Mercurial, you can do this: Pop the latest commit from the repository and save it in a "patch" (`hg qimport`). The result is the repo without any trace of the latest commit plus a patch that would give you the starting state.

So the recipe would be to pop stuff from the repo until the commit to modify becomes HEAD. Pop that, too, modify the patch (or apply the patch without commit and modify the workspace).

Now you can commit the new version and apply all the other patches.

Since Git and Mercurial are very similar, there is probably a Git command to achieve the same but I don't know its name. Maybe this answer can help: https://serverfault.com/questions/12373/how-do-i-edit-gits-history-to-correct-an-incorrect-email-address-name

Comment: Changing others' commit is not polite maybe...it's better to change only your own commit.

Comment: "Better" is the wrong term. If your new commit collides with the commit of someone else, you will have to make changes. This isn't an issue of "good/bad" but of pure mathematics. If that doesn't suit you, Git, Mercurial and any other DVCS isn't the right tool for you.

Comment: Git can do this too (before Hg do). But the asker want to keep the commitid (the long one, not the local single number one) -- I don't think Hg can do that.

Comment: @J-16: I don't see where he says he wants to keep the commit ID. The question says "How to *change* the SHA-1..."

Answer (score 0):

Okay, let's see if this helps.

WARNING:

- This break (some) pull / push / fetch.
- Not all git command support this.
- It does not share with other users.
- This does not change the commit, it replace it.

Are you sure you want to do this?
Scroll down if yes.

---

This is called [graft point](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/GraftPoint). You create a file `.git/info/grafts` and have the following info:

```
<commit-id> <new-parent-of-the-commit>
```

Let's say you have this:

```
/---D
A---B---C
```

Now you want to replace `B` with `D` (without changing the commit id), you put this in graft:

```
<commit-id-of-C> <commit-id-of-D>
```

It keeps the old `commitid`, with the limitation stated above.

Comment: (And I lied again, git 1.6.6 have `git-replace`. But it is **even uglier**. So ugly that I won't try to explain it. Check the ProGit blog if you want)

Comment: You can make it permanent with `git filter-branch` but that does re-write the commit SHA1 values, which you said you didn't want...