# Batch delete remote commits from a list of SHA-1 list

Tags: git, gitlab, commit, rebase

I want to delete many commits from my repo history. By deleting, I mean that I want them to completely disappear from my remote repository on GitLab. Pure and simple. No history, no trace.
I know this is not recommended but those are duplicates and they contain sensitive information.

I have a list of SHA-1 like this:

```
3816b7652c4147216293d1fac3dee2f377417979
0f0a95f4d15a2a8d176f548bde47259956cbb859
90cd0dc615d6928460861da70f024039ce18e06f
f8a371aff5301c69825dbd6aec7898fb2c122a79
619dd79966ef4636134bc55f1ef3f03f94cb9dd4
a556b303021c2da0094d42605ce426ef9e74a765  
.  
.
.
```

They are the commits I want gone. They can be on the `master` branch or other branches.
`git rebase -i <SHA>^` could be a great tool and I don't really mind finding the lines matching my list by hand. But when I save the `git-rebase-todo` file I have merging errors. I don't want to be disturbed by those, I just want to delete the commits as if they never existed. That's all.

Answer (score 2):

You would need a combination of:

- [`git replace`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-replace) to replace a commit by its parent (if the parent is not part of your list), [as seen here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7076451/6309);
- `git filter branch` to make that replacement permanent (changing all the sha1 of your remaining commits in the process, by the way)

That need to be scripted as this is not a native feature in Git.