# using git rebase in the master branch

Tags: git, git-merge, git-rebase

I am using git for quite some time and wanted to use `rebase` command. Earlier I have used only the `merge` command.

I have my changes done to my feature branch which I need to merge with my master branch. I can go ahead and merge my changes to my master branch by running the `git merge` command from the master branch. But can I use the rebase command to get my branch changes into my master? From the documentation, I understood that rebase will be done from the feature branches to merge the changes from the master to my feature branch. Is my understanding correct or I need to use the git merge command for my scenario.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> But can I use the rebase command to get my branch changes into my master?

Yes:

```
git checkout feature
git rebase master  # replay feature commits on top of master
git checkout master
git merge feature # fast-forward
```

Make sure you are the only one working on that branch, as a rebase will change (rewrite) its history, and you will need a `git push --force` to publish your work.

See more at:

- "[When do you use `git rebase` instead of `git merge`?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/804178/6309)",
- "[About Git's merge and rebase](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7062773/6309)".