# GitHub: Difference between Accept current changes and Incoming changes

Tags: github

Problem occurs when codes are conflict.

[image: VSCode merge resolution]

As you see in image given above that four options are there

1. Accept incoming changes
2. Accept current changes
3. Accept Both changes
4. Compare changes

I want to know the difference between `Accept Current changes` and `Accept Incoming changes`

Answer (score 172, accepted):

It depends on the type of operation ([merge or rebase](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7062773/6309)) leading to that conflict.
When you are trying to resolve conflicts in Git, you are typically dealing with two sets of changes:

1. **Changes from your Current Branch**: Often the branch you are currently working on or have checked out. In your explanation, this is described as "what you have" or "the destination of the merge".
2. **Changes from the Incoming Branch**: The branch you are trying to merge into your current branch (during a merge) or the branch you are attempting to apply on top of another branch (during a rebase). This is "what you merge" or "the source of the merge".

Now, in the context of the conflict resolution options in VSCode:

- **Accept Incoming changes**: That will discard the conflicting changes from your current branch ("what you have") and keep the changes from the incoming branch ("what you merge").
- **Accept current changes**: That will keep the conflicting changes from your current branch ("what you have") and discard the changes from the incoming branch ("what you merge").

It is important to understand that [during a **rebase**, the roles of "current branch" and "incoming branch" are essentially reversed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2960751/6309). In a rebase, your current branch is being applied on top of the incoming branch. So, when faced with conflicts:

- "**Current changes**" during a rebase will refer to the branch onto which you are rebasing (usually the base branch).
- "**Incoming changes**" during a rebase will refer to the branch that you are trying to rebase (the changes you are attempting to apply on top of another branch).

Comment: So to make sure I understand:
If I'm on BRANCH_1 and I run "git checkout master" and get conflicts:
Incoming changes are what the file is like on master
Current changes are what I did on BRANCH_1, correct?

Comment: @NickTydryszewski Yes, provided you did a `git checkout -m master` (https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout#Documentation/git-checkout.txt--m)

Comment: @VonC "Option 1 (='Accept incoming changes') would ignore completely what you merge, and keep what you had." Is that true? My feeling tells me it's the opposite.

Comment: @danzel Agreed. I have edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for the "rebase is reversed" tip, I was having trouble with this.

Comment: This answer is more confusing than it is helpful. "What you had" and "what you merge" are just so ambiguous, especially since you're also trying to explain what happens in a rebase.

Comment: @Mdev Thank you for your feedback. I have rewritten the answer to clarify that point.

Answer (score 60):

If it's a conflict due to a rebase, you could always imagine like so -

1. Your master branch is fixed
2. A feature branch that originated from an older commit on master, is shifting itself from there to the latest commit on master (that's what a rebase is, at its core).

Now, if you see from the point of view of master -

- `incoming changes` are the ones that move **to** master (i.e. changes in your feature branch), hence the term.
- `current changes` are the ones that are already present in master (i.e. ones done by fellow developers or yourself on master).

In case of merge conflicts, as suggested by @VonC, the terminology is reversed.

Comment: So, if I was on my feature branch and I ran `git pull --rebase origin master` Will `incoming changes` be the changes on master?

Comment: @MahmoudTokura technically, yes. But in practice, we almost never merge master into our feature branch.

Answer (score 39):

You are on a **feature** branch

##### 1. `git pull origin master`

###### Current changes

Changes on your current **feature** branch.

###### Incoming changes

Changes you are pulling from i.e the **master** branch

---

##### 2. `git pull origin master --rebase`

During rebase your feature branch changes are applied on top of the commits that are already there in master branch.

###### Current changes

Changes on the **master** branch.

###### Incoming changes

Changes on the **feature** branch.

---

* After a rebase, you need to force push your branch. Use `--force-with-lease` instead of `--force`

Comment: Well, this is pretty confusing... Why does git not name the changes after the source?  After all, the default merge strategy is hidden somewhere in gitconfig.